# Order Emails are not generated :: SMTP configurations required :: Magento community open source

Tags: php, magento2, magento-2.3

Magento 2.3.1  order emails are not getting generated after successful order.

OS: Ubunut 18.04
Payment Gateway: Fatzebra

Used following code to generate emails.
https://magecomp.com/blog/send-order-confirmation-email-after-successful-payment-magento-2/

I have also tried to make it work by disabling store->configuration->Sales->Sales Email->Order to No/yes both options but still not working.

Comment: What does `var/log` says about it? Are there any logs there?

Comment: @joshua no logs

Comment: Are you using SMTP to send emails?

Comment: @joshua I figured it out smtp needed to be configured . Since magento community doesn't come with proper smtp configurations (stores->configuration->Advanced->system->Mail Sending Settings) so I sued MagePal free extension. There is also another smtp extension by mageplaza but for me its now working with my magento version 2.3.1.

Comment: Glad to be able to help :) When it comes to mails, it usually boils down to SMTP. In most cases, SMTP must be configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use magepal or Magepalaza smtp extension whichever works with your magento version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SMTP for Magento 2 for sending emails.

I use the SMTP extension by Mageplaza on my projects.

Comment: which version of magento are u using

Comment: I'm using Magento 2.2.4 currently.

Comment: Im using magento 2.3.1 mageplaza I tried but didnt work although they say its compatible now.  https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-smtp/issues/129. However, MagePal worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Use the extension which works best for your current version. I use mageplaza because it is stable in my current magento version.